# Router management for root page in the CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

My cakephp version is 3.2. I want to manage CMS page in routers. My cms page will looks like -

```
http://www.sitename.com/about-us
http://www.sitename.com/contact-us
http://www.siteame.com/privacy-policy
http://www.sitename.com/faq etc. etc.
```

All the above url is calling one action `http://wwwsitename.com/pages/cms_page/seo-url`

seo-url = 'about-us', 'contact-us', 'privacy-policy', 'faq' etc..

Here is my routers already calling the default root url is -

```
$routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'index']);
```

Tell me how to manage CMS page in routers?

**EDIT**

*Table:* pages

```
+----+-----------+------------+-------------+
| id | title     | seo        | description |
+----+-----------+------------+-------------+
|  1 | About Us  | about-us   | content here|
|  2 | Contact Us| contact-us | content here|
+----+-----------+------------+-------------+
```

If site admin will change my `about-us` seo column name to `aboutus` then my URL will look - `http://www.sitename.com/aboutus`

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213883/cakephp-routing-home-slug-as-url

Answer (score 1):

is the cms_page action of the pages controller the only action accessed in the entire application?

if so try:

```
Router::connect('/*', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'cms_page']);
```

**Edit**

You didn't explain that you have other pages on the page. With this in mind you **have** to define each route separately.

try:

```
Router::connect('/about-us', ['controller'=>'Users', 'action' => 'index', 'about-us']);
Router::connect('/contact-us', ['controller'=>'Users', 'action' => 'index','contact-us']);
Router::connect('/privacy-policy', ['controller'=>'Users', 'action' => 'index','privacy-policy']);
Router::connect('/faq', ['controller'=>'Users', 'action' => 'index','faq']);
```

> http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#routes-configuration

Tested and worked fine for me.

Comment: Yeah you didn't mention there were other controllers in your application. Had you mentioned this out of the gate I could have given you a better answer sooner.. see my edit. cheers

Comment: @JasonJoslin I saw your edited answer. But You have added static in routes `about-us`, `contact-us` etc. But If site admin will change `about-us` to `aboutus` then my current page `about-us`. So I am getting null data in the about page.

Comment: Sorry I  can't help you any further. The way I have shown is all I know.  Sorry